# Most performant way to crawl json object array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a list with ~1000 possible file extensions and it's aliases. The structure looks like this:

```
var iconMap = [
    { icon: 'photoshop', extensions: ['psd'], format: 'svg' },
    { icon: 'photoshop2', extensions: ['psd'], format: 'svg', disabled: true },
    { icon: 'php', extensions: ['php1', 'php2', 'php3', 'php4', 'php5', 'php6', 'phps', 'phpsa', 'phpt', 'phtml', 'phar'], format: 'svg' }]
```

I want to get the 'icon' property for the according extension. Therefore I want to create a `getExtensionIcon(fileExtension)` function which should return:

```
var phpIcon = getExtensionIcon('php') // 'php'
var pharIcon = getExtensionIcon('phar') // 'php'
var php5Icon = getExtensionIcon('php5') // 'php'
```

**My question:**

I only got a few ideas which would be very ineffecient, so I am curious how you would realize the getExtensionicon function?

Comment: What are your ideas? The way it is set up, your only real choice is a for loop.

Comment: psd should return?

Comment: what should it return for extension `psd` - my first thought is to "convert" that array into an object with keys being the extension and value being the icon

Comment: for 'psd' it should return photoshop

Comment: will there ever be a case where one extension could have more than one icon?

Comment: @JaromandaX nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it - this "pre-processes" the iconMap once, creating an object that keys `extension` with a value of `icon`

```js
var iconMap = [
    { icon: 'photoshop', extensions: ['psd'], format: 'svg' },
    { icon: 'photoshop2', extensions: ['psd'], format: 'svg', disabled: true },
    { icon: 'php', extensions: ['php1', 'php2', 'php3', 'php4', 'php5', 'php6', 'phps', 'phpsa', 'phpt', 'phtml', 'phar'], format: 'svg' }
];
var getExtensionIcon = (src => {
    var extensions = src.filter(item => !item.disabled).reduce((result, item) => {
        item.extensions.forEach(ext => {
            result[ext] = item.icon;
        });
        return result;
    }, {});
    return ext => extensions[ext];
})(iconMap);
console.log('psd is', getExtensionIcon('psd'));
console.log('php1 is', getExtensionIcon('php1'));
```

Comment: Respect! Took me a while to completely understand it

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, it has the `$.grep()` function which seems like a good fit for this purpose:

```
function getExtensionIcon(arr, lang){
    var result = $.grep(arr, function(e){ return e.extensions.indexOf(lang) != -1; });
    return result[0].icon;
}
```

I don't really know how performant this is, but you should at least give it a try ;)

Testing with your Example:

```js
function getExtensionIcon(arr, lang){
    var result = $.grep(arr, function(e){ return e.extensions.indexOf(lang) != -1; });
    return result[0].icon;
}

var iconMap = [
    { icon: 'photoshop', extensions: ['psd'], format: 'svg' },
    { icon: 'photoshop2', extensions: ['psd'], format: 'svg', disabled: true },
    { icon: 'php', extensions: ['php1', 'php2', 'php3', 'php4', 'php5', 'php6', 'phps', 'phpsa', 'phpt', 'phtml', 'phar'], format: 'svg' }];
    
console.log(getExtensionIcon(iconMap, "php6"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I found a [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/filterings/2) on that topic. Normal for-Loop is the fastest and $.grep takes the second place